# How do you sort a list in Jinja2?

Tags: python, sorting, jinja2

I am trying to do this:

```
 {% for movie in movie_list | sort(movie.rating) %}
```

But that's not right...the documentation is vague...how do you do this in Jinja2?

Answer (score 223, accepted):

As of version 2.6, Jinja2's built-in sort filter allows you to specify an attribute to sort by:

```
{% for movie in movie_list|sort(attribute='rating') %}
```

See http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/templates/#sort

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted.  By the way, does it work with both types of attributes...you know __getattr__ and __getitem__ ?  (because I can't remember whether "movies" were objects or dictionaries)

Comment: @Nick: I did a quick test, and it seemed to work with both objects and dicts.

Comment: Nice, this also works for a tuple index: `list_of_tuples|sort(attribute='0')`

Comment: It could be handy to display values in reverse orders (it could be interesting for ratings for example), in this case just use the option `reverse=True`.

Answer (score 47):

If you want to sort in ascending order

```
{% for movie in movie_list|sort(attribute='rating') %}
```

If you want to sort in descending order

```
{% for movie in movie_list|sort(attribute='rating', reverse = True) %}
```