# How do you sort a list in Jinja2 by X element?

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm looking at the answer in this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959386/how-do-you-sort-a-list-in-jinja2#) but my list doesn't have an attribute. I'm trying to sort by unique string in the second list element. This doesn't seem to work:

{% for item in whole_list | sort(whole_list.1) %}

Comment: please provide at least a sample input and expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not currently documented, but Jinja2's `sort` filter also accepts an index for `attribute` transparently. So the same syntax will work:

```
{% for item in whole_list | sort(attribute=1) %}
anything with item
{% endfor %}
```

That works because in general [`Environment.getitem()`](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/jinja2/blob/46acbf02ed9ab58c7a92553c95790e75bdc3c930/jinja2/environment.py#L386) is used for both attributes and collection items resolution.