# Get sorted list of folders with Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have **OS X "El capitan" 10.11.6** and I am using  **Ansible 2.1.1.0** to run some maintenance tasks on a remote Linux server **Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial**. I am trying to get the following list of folders sorted on the remote machine (Linux), so I can remove the old ones when needed:

```
/releases/0.0.0
/releases/0.0.1
/releases/0.0.10
/releases/1.0.0
/releases/1.0.5
/releases/2.0.0
```

I have been trying with the module [find](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/find_module.html) in Ansible, but it returns a not sorted list. Is there an easy way to achieve this with Ansible?

Comment: What do you mean you are "trying to get"? What is your input, what do you want to pass the output to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Interesting solutions, thanks a lot guys. But I think I have found the easiest way in **Ubuntu**, just using `ls -v /releases/` will apply natural sorting to all folders:

```
- name: List of releases in ascendent order  
  command: ls -v /releases/
  register: releases

- debug: msg={{ releases.stdout_lines }}
```

The response is:

```
ok: [my.remote.com] => {
    "msg": [
        "0.0.0",
        "0.0.1",
        "0.0.10",
        "1.0.0",
        "1.0.5",
        "2.0.0"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Interesting... how is `ls -v` gives you numeric sort?

Comment: Having a look at `ls --help` I just found this:
`ls -v` **Natural sort of (version) numbers within text.**

Comment: I have edited my answer, Originally I wrote "numeric sort" but this is actually **natural sort**.

Comment: This will work only with GNU `ls`, not `ls` on a mac.

Comment: You right Konstantin, I was using OS X to run Ansible but the command `ls -v` was actually executed on the remote server **Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial**. It's good to know it won't work on OS X

Comment: `ls -1 /releases/ | sort -n -k1` works on Linux and Unix systems as well (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/34006/335249). As the Ansible `command` module does not support stream operations like `|` you will have to use the `shell` module instead.

Answer (score 25):

You can sort items with `sort` filter:

```
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
    - find: path="/tmp" patterns="test*"
      register: files

    - debug: msg="{{ files.files | sort(attribute='ctime') | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Just change sort attribute to your need.
**But beware** that string sort is not numeric, so `/releases/1.0.5` will go after `/releases/1.0.10`.

Comment: I didn't know about the jinja2 sort filter, thanks @Konstantin Suvorov. But as you said, this solution doesn't meet the spec.

Comment: you can sort reverse with `sort(attribute='ctime', reverse=True)` (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39051279/2799887))

Answer (score 2):

If you want to find files older than a period, maybe `age` and `age_stamp` parameters of `find` module can help you. For example:

```
# Recursively find /tmp files older than 4 weeks and equal or greater than 1 megabyte
- find: paths="/tmp" age="4w" size="1m" recurse=yes
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to do is real simple but the standard `ansible` modules doesn't quite have what you needed.

As an alternative you can write your own script using your favorite programming language then use the `copy` module to pass that script to the host and use `command` to execute it. When done, use `file` to remove that script.

The downside of it is that the target host will need to have the required executable to run your script. For instance if you are doing a python script then the target host will need `python`

Example:

```
- name: Send your script to the target host
  copy: src=directory_for_scripts/my_script.sh dest=/tmp/my_script.sh
- name: Execute my script on target host
  command: >
          /bin/bash /tmp/my_script.sh
- name: Clean up the target host by removing script
  file: path=/tmp/my_script.sh state=absent
```