# What is the sorting order of the return value by with_fileglob?

Tags: ansible

I have read the Ansible document but I can't find out the sorting order of the result of the [`with_fileglob`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/fileglob_lookup.html).

For example: I have a task to print out a list of items that under the folder chapters.

```yaml
    - name: fileglob test
      debug:
        msg: 
          - "Hello {{ item }}"
        with_fileglob: 
        - ./books/chapters/*
```

My test data:

```
$ ls books/chapters/
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:37 0.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:37 1.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:37 2.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:37 A.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:38 B.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:38 Z.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:38 a.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:38 b.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:37 chapter.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 24 16:24 chapter1.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 24 16:24 chapter2.json
-rw-r--r-- Jan 25 20:38 z.json
```

I got the same order every time I run my playbook. Do you have any idea how this order is made up?

```
TASK [test : fileglob test] 
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/B.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/B.json"] 
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/0.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/0.json"] 
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/chapter2.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/chapter2.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/chapter1.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/chapter1.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/1.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/1.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/b.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/b.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/Z.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/Z.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/A.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/A.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/z.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/z.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/2.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/2.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/a.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/a.json"]
}
ok: [127.0.0.1] => (item=/ansible/./books/chapters/chapter.json) => {
    "msg": ["Hello /ansible/./books/chapters/chapter.json"]
}
```

Comment: Since Ansible is a Python application, this is probably related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773584/how-is-pythons-glob-glob-ordered

Comment: So, as pointed by the accepted answer, you could compare Ansible's sorting to the result of `ls -U`

Comment: In case a sorted file list is required, [get sorted list of folders with Ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39424296/6771046).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comments, it helps a lots. According to the man page of ls, option -U means => do not sort; list entries in directory order. So it depends on the file system implementation to decide how to list entries in a directory.