# Sort dict of dict in jinja2 loop

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, jinja2

How can I sort a dict like

```
my_dict = {
    'abc': {'name': 'B', 'is_sth': True},
    'xyz': {'name': 'A', 'is_sth': True}
}
```

by `name` in Jinja?

I've tried `{% for id, data in my_dict|dictsort(by='value') if data.is_sth %}` but doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: what do you expect?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre he expects

`{'xyz': {'name': 'A', 'is_sth': True}, 'abc': {'name': 'B', 'is_sth': True}}`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**Solution:**

`my_dict.items()|sort(attribute='1.name')`

Comment: Some explanation would help, I understand "name" but what does the "1." relate to?

Comment: `.items()` returns a tuple of two elements: key and value. `1` relates to the 2nd element i.e. the value and `.name` relates to the key from the internal dict.

Comment: this answer proposes you don't need the 'items()' call: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5490174/1518225

Comment: So i understand i can reference in this way any inner key, does not matter the complexity of nesting ? like 1.name.x.y.z ?

Comment: @Stefan you do need it if you are unpacking the ```key, value``` pairs as the question's code does. In the answer you're linking they get them as a single variable.

Answer (score 5):

jinja2 has a perfect solution for it

> do_dictsort(value, case_sensitive=False, by='key')

```
{% for item in mydict|dictsort %}
    sort the dict by key, case insensitive

{% for item in mydict|dicsort(true) %}
    sort the dict by key, case sensitive

{% for item in mydict|dictsort(false, 'value') %}
    sort the dict by key, case insensitive, sorted
    normally and ordered by value.
```

Answer (score 0):

if you can live with ordering your data outside jinja and then just displaying it, you could do this:

```
from jinja2 import Template
from collections import OrderedDict

tmplt = Template('''
{% for id, data in od.items() if data.is_sth %}
{{id}}, {{data}}
{% endfor %}
''')

od = OrderedDict((key, value) for key, value in
                 sorted(my_dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1]['name']))

print(tmplt.render(od = od))
```

which gives:

```
xyz, {'name': 'A', 'is_sth': True}

abc, {'name': 'B', 'is_sth': True}
```

other than that you'd probably have to create a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/api/#custom-filters).

Comment: That would work, but I would rather to order it in jinja. Actually I think I've found a solution: `{% for id, data in my_dict.items()|sort(attribute='1.name') if data.is_sth %}`

Comment: @mvidalgarcia ha! i was trying something along those lines but did not the the quotes around `'1.name'` right... you can post what you found here as an answer yourself! (but only 24h after the question if i remember correctly). good luck! (so it's `my_dict.items()|sort(attribute='1.name')`, right?)

Comment: oh, sorry about the last question; you had the jinja statement in your comment already...

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness...

Jinja has (at least?) two different ways of sorting the dictionaries. One is `dictsort` and the other is `sort`.

#### dictsort

```
{% for key, value in dictionary|dictsort %}
```

This way of doing it gives you the `key, value` pairs directly, without `.items()`, and sorts the dictionaries by `key`.

#### sort

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items()|sort(attribute="sort_by_?") %}
```

This way of doing it needs you to ask for the `.items()`, just like standard python would. But, it lets you specify a somewhat custom way to sort them.

Within the attribute string (it needs to be a string) you can use `0` to reference the dictionary `key` and `1` to reference the dictionary `value`. If you want a specific inner `key` that exists inside of that `value`, you can access it by a  `.` (examples below).

Also, you can use jinja's `|` stuff inside the attribute string if you need to convert strings to integers or whatever (it goes inside of the string).

**sort examples**

Sorting by `value["name"]`

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items()|sort(attribute="1.name")%}
```

Sorting by `key` (but the stupid way, since this would be the default if you don't specify any attribute)

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items()|sort(attribute="0")%}
```

Sorting by `int(key)` so that `"10"` doesn't end up before `"2"` when you have numbers stored as strings.

```
{% for key, value in dictionary.items()|sort(attribute="0|int")%}
```