# jinja2 dictsort not sorting

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I would like to do a jinja for loop on my dictionary and sort by the value of `name`

dict example

```yaml
    things:
      1:
        name: afoo
      2:
        name: zfoo
      3:
        name: bfoo
      4:
        name: cfoo
```

Jinja gathered from documentation

```
{%- for thing, property in things|dictsort('name') %}
  foo "{{ property.name }}" bar
{%- endfor %}
```

results in

```
foo afoo bar
foo zfoo bar
foo bfoo bar
foo cfoo bar
```

I've tried quite a few iterations of dictsort() and sort() using different values in place of `name` like `property.name` or `thing.name` and had no luck, obviously I'm missing something, the documentation on this sort function is pretty lite.

Comment: Question is a dupe, search never pulled up the other question for whatever reason. Here's how I solved mine. {%- for thing, property in things.items()|sort(attribute='1.name') %}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{%- for thing, property in things.items()|sort(attribute='1.name') %}
```

solved the problem.

[Sort dict of dict in jinja2 loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43541890/sort-dict-of-dict-in-jinja2-loop)

Comment: This example helped me to understand. I replaced thing, property to key,value. Things to mydict and you just have to change "name" to the value you need to sort