# Is it possible to sort a list by length in Jinja2?

Tags: python, sorting, jinja2

I want to sort a list by length, but I'm not sure if it is possible with Jinja2:

```
{% for item in item_list | sort(length) %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sort a list in Jinja2?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959386/how-do-you-sort-a-list-in-jinja2)

Comment: @juliansalas it is by attribute, I would like by length of items

Comment: Why not sorted it in your view?

Comment: That's why I'm asking if it's possible or not, if not to do it in the view

Comment: seem be not is possible from ninja template, try to do from your view is more easy and flexible.

Comment: Also a Jinja2 custom filter can help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `item` is your custom class, you can override `__lt__` and you'll be able to sort directly with the `sort` filter. Since Jinja 2.6, you have a `length` attribute on your item, you can do so with `sort(attribute='length')`. Taken from the [Jinja2 sort filter documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#sort)