# Sorting html option list in python

Tags: python, html, jinja2

I have the following code in index.html file and I am trying to sort the output A-Z.

Would it be possible by editing this code only?

```
{% for x in data.pairs %}
<option>{{ x }}</option>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you sort a list in Jinja2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1959386/how-do-you-sort-a-list-in-jinja2)

Comment: If thats the case then this should do it?
{% for x in data.pairs | sort(x) %}
 <option>{{ x }}</option>
      {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{% for x in data.pairs|sort %}
<option>{{ x }}</option>
{% endfor %}`
This works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this.

`{% for x in data.paris.all|dictsort:"variable name" %}
     {{ x }}
{% endfor %}`

Please follow the below mentioned documentation for details. Select your desire django version.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-dictsort